# How to align the div with class pull-right vertically center in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a form line with a label an input field and a button. The first two element should be align left the button should be aligned right.
I've tried the pull-right class, but it ruins the vertical alignment of the button. I want it to be vertically centered. I've tried to set the line-height, but it ruins the vertical alignment of the label. (I want the label to be aligned vertically center relative to the input too)

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group col-sm-11">
       <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Email</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pull-right">
        <button>Add</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/i8jmEowKaKOcM2P8N225?p=preview

[image]

Comment: Use `form-inline` instead of `form-horizontal`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/1ph4kz30/

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle with the button wrapped inside a <div> with the `pull-right` class. http://jsfiddle.net/1ph4kz30/1/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments: To display multiple form elements in one row, use the `form-inline` class. This applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide (so watch the example below in full screen to see the effect).

See [Bootstraps documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) for more information.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```